# How do I send post and header data with Chromium?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, chromium

I am attempting to convert some code from TWebBrowser to Chromium but am having trouble figuring out how to send post and header data with an HTTP request.

Below is the TWebBrowser functionality I'm trying to implement.

```
var
VHeader, PostData: OleVariant;


PostData := VarArrayCreate([0, Length(XMLString) - 1], varByte) ;    
HeaderData := 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'+ '\n';

WebBrowser1.Navigate(StrUrl,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,PostData,VHeader);
```

How do I do the equivalent with Chromium?

Comment: In this thread there's [`the example`](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/delphichromiumembedded/r1_ytEvBHEs) of a POST request made by Delphi CEF wrapper author himself. If I'll get to Delphi and find a place to test that, I'll post this as an answer (if someone won't be faster :-)

Comment: So I got it working.. (with your example TLama) All except for adding the header data.. My application seems to run fine without it (or its already set by default)..  But if anyone knows how to do it with the header data, or wants to still answer I would still be interested..  Feel free to put that link as the answer and i'll accept it..  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Due to a missing documentation for Delphi Chromium Embedded, I'll refer the needed requirements for sending web requests for the C++ version of CEF. So, you need to use the [`LoadRequest`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs/projects/%28default%29/CefFrame.html#LoadRequest%28CefRefPtr%3CCefRequest%3E%29) method for sending requests in Chromium. For using it, you need the object instance of the [`CefRequest`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs/projects/%28default%29/CefRequest.html) request object class along with the [`HeaderMap`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs/projects/%28default%29/CefRequest..HeaderMap.html) and [`CefPostData`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs/projects/%28default%29/CefPostData.html) objects for request header and data specification.

Expanding on Henri Gourvest's (author of the Delphi CEF wrapper) example from [`this thread`](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/delphichromiumembedded/r1_ytEvBHEs), you can in Delphi try something like the following pseudo-code:

```
uses
  ceflib;

function CreateField(const AValue: AnsiString): ICefPostDataElement;
begin
  Result := TCefPostDataElementRef.New;
  Result.SetToBytes(Length(AValue), PAnsiChar(AValue));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Header: ICefStringMultimap;
  Data: ICefPostData;
  Request: ICefRequest;
begin
  Header := TCefStringMultimapOwn.Create;
  Header.Append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  Data := TCefPostDataRef.New;
  Data.AddElement(CreateField('Data.id=27'));
  Data.AddElement(CreateField('&Data.title=title'));
  Data.AddElement(CreateField('&Data.body=body'));

  Request := TCefRequestRef.New;
  Request.Flags := WUR_FLAG_NONE;
  Request.Assign('http://example.com/', 'POST', Data, Header);

  Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.LoadRequest(Request);
end;
```

The same should do another version of the above code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Header: ICefStringMultimap;
  Data: ICefPostData;
  Request: ICefRequest;
begin
  Request := TCefRequestRef.New;
  Request.Url := 'http://example.com/';
  Request.Method := 'POST';
  Request.Flags := WUR_FLAG_NONE;

  Header := TCefStringMultimapOwn.Create;
  Header.Append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  Request.SetHeaderMap(Header);

  Data := TCefPostDataRef.New;
  Data.AddElement(CreateField('Data.id=27'));
  Data.AddElement(CreateField('&Data.title=title'));
  Data.AddElement(CreateField('&Data.body=body'));
  Request.PostData := Data;

  Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.LoadRequest(Request);
end;
```

Comment: He meant "UR_FLAG_NONE", located in "uCEFConstants.pas"