# Delphi DCEF - Chromium - how to fill in a form?

Tags: delphi, chromium

I am really struggling to find any examples on the Internet about how to use DCEF3 to fill in a form, and then submit it?

Any code examples would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you directly [`post a request`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12978338/960757) ?

Comment: No, I need to automate the filling in of a form :)

Comment: [Link (Russian)](http://parsing-and-i.blogspot.com/2013/02/tchromium-how-to-fill-and-submit-form.html) - see code example.

Comment: This method does work, however I am doing like a multi-step form. I wait for the page to load using; (pseudo) `while Loaded = false application.processmessages`. Clicking the submit button with Javascript makes this condition not work for some reason, and the CR component always thinks the browser is loaded, even before the submitted form has finished loading.

Answer (score 3):

If it's still an active question - I'd try it with javascript calls, they worked well for me.
First wait for page loaded *event* OnLoadEnd, then call something like this

```
crm.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript(  'document.forms[0].elements[0].value="xy";' );
```

Actual Javascript could be different.

To submit form javascript again:

```
crm.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript(  'document.forms[0].submit();' );
```